# Execute code before state restoration happens (macOs)

Tags: swift, xcode, nsdocument, nsapplication, state-restoration

I'm writing a document-based application for Mac in Swift 4, which, according to my client needs, has to show a licensing window were the user will provide its license key.

I show this window at the `applicationWillFinishLaunching()` method. While this window is active, the state restoration methods run in the background and load previous nsdocuments, or create empty ones if there were no previous.
I want to avoid that, I want to be able to choose when restoration and behaving like a document based app starts.

I've tried to intercept the launching of the app in the appDelegate method `applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile(_ sender: NSApplication)` but I was not successful. Then I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564290/why-isnt-applicationshouldopenuntitledfile-being-called) that this method doesn't gets called if application state restoration is active.
To confirm that, I deactivated the restoration, and then last documents or empty documents were not loaded / created anymore as expected. Great!

But then, I loose the nice restoration functionality.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this: displaying a licensing screen in a document-based app, halting the  restoration methods, and manually calling them after app is licensed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is Objective C, but this is how I did it to show a dialog in which the user has to accept some license conditions:

In my AppDelegate, I got a property `licenseDialogOpen` which is set to false when the app starts.

```
@synthesize licenseDialogOpen;

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.licenseDialogOpen = FALSE;
    }
    return self;
}
```

In my Document class I overwrote `windowControllerDidLoadNib`

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)windowController {
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:windowController];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [NSApp delegate];

    if (!appDelegate.licenseDialogOpen) {
        NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        [alert setMessageText:NSLocalizedString(@"License conditions and disclaimer:", nil)];
        [alert setInformativeText:NSLocalizedString(@"License bla bla disclaimer bla bla bla", nil)];
        [alert setAlertStyle:NSAlertStyleWarning];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Accept", nil)];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Quit", nil)];

        [alert.window makeFirstResponder:[[alert buttons] firstObject]];

        appDelegate.licenseDialogOpen = TRUE;
        NSModalResponse answer = [alert runModal];
        if (answer != NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {
            for (NSWindow *window in [NSApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
                [window close];
            }
            [NSApp terminate:self];
        }
    }
}
```

So the first document window which is opened shows the modal dialog and quits the app when the user does not accept.

You can [add a NSTextField to a NSAlert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387341/how-to-create-and-get-return-value-from-cocoa-dialog/7387395#7387395) in order to ask for the license key.